Выходит ошибка при запуске тестов No module named 'app'
Структура проекта:
weather_forecast
├── app
│   ├── pages/
│   │   ├── router.py
│   ├── tests/
│   │   ├── conftest.py
│   ├── main.py

При запуске pytest выходит ошибка ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'. Находился  и в папке weather_forecast, и в app.
Можете подсказать из-за чего это происходит??


В целом, имеет смысл вынести тесты из приложения вообще, запускать просто командой pytest папки weather_forecast.
Без изменения структуры папок тесты в пакете нужно запускать такой командой:
pytest --pyargs app.tests

Документация: Run tests from packages
